# using map type creates gcc error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’

Tags: c++, gcc, dictionary, bitset

I am new to linux, using terminal in Ubuntu virual box environment. I cannot figure out what and why these errors are happening, and they don't seem to match a missing ';' or #define conflict.

Here are the errors I get from the gcc compiler:

```
my_predictor.h:82:42: error: template argument 2 is invalid
my_predictor.h:82:42: error: template argument 4 is invalid
my_predictor.h:84:9: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’
my_predictor.h:84:23: error: ‘g’ does not name a type
my_predictor.h:84:44: error: ‘g’ does not name a type
my_predictor.h:91:42: error: template argument 2 is invalid
my_predictor.h:91:42: error: template argument 4 is invalid
my_predictor.h:93:9: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’
my_predictor.h:93:23: error: ‘f’ does not name a type
my_predictor.h:93:39: error: ‘f’ does not name a type
my_predictor.h: In member function ‘virtual branch_update* local_predictor::predict(branch_info&)’:
my_predictor.h:107:57: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:111:40: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h: In member function ‘virtual void local_predictor::update(branch_update*, bool, unsigned int)’:
my_predictor.h:121:62: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:124:46: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:125:33: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:127:41: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:128:29: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:131:33: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:132:30: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:135:33: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
my_predictor.h:136:30: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
```

I think the key problem is in the declaration and initialization of the Map construct with an index key, and then a bitset object which is a string of bits. It seems to create the later errors with the array [] operations (which are supposed to be valid from what I found on cplusplus.com/reference/map site).

Here is my code:

```
1:// my_predictor.h
// This file contains a sample gshare_predictor class.
// It is a simple 32,768-entry gshare with a history length of 15.

5:#include <bitset>
#include <map>
7:using namespace std;

64:class local_predictor : public branch_predictor {
65:public:
#define LHBITLEN 10
#define PREDCNTR 2
#define LOCHISTTABLERNG 4096
#define LOCPREDRNG 1024
70:     local_update u;
        branch_info bcopy;

        // otherwise ints, where each will be multiplied by 10, then add 1 if taken/true. Initial test case to change if 10 bits long already

75:     // ?correct location? Bit array of length 10 for local history table value entries
        bitset<LHBITLEN> lhthistval; 
        bitset<PREDCNTR> lpcounter;

        // initialize to 0's 
80:       // lhthistval.reset();

        std::map<int, (bitset<LHBITLEN>) > lochisttab;
        //map<int, (bitset<10>) > lht;
        for (int g=0; g < LOCHISTTABLERNG; g++) {
85:            //const int j = g;
            lochisttab[g] = lhthistval.reset();
            //lht.insert(pair<int, (bitset<LHBITLEN>)>(j, lhthistval.reset()));
        }

90:
    std::map<int, (bitset<PREDCNTR>) > locprediction;
    //map<int, (bitset<2>) > locpredict;
    for (int f=0; f < LOCPREDRNG; f++) {
        //const int j = f;
95:        //locpredict.insert(pair<int, (bitset<PREDCNTR>)>(j,lpcounter.reset()));
        locprediction[f] = lpcounter.reset();
    }


100:    local_predictor (void) {
    }

    branch_update *predict (branch_info & b) {
        bcopy = b;
105:        // address for locpredict based on value by modulus (remainder) of branch address divide by 4096
        int braddr = static_cast<int>(b.address % LOCHISTTABLERNG);
        bitset<LHBITLEN> address = lochisttab[braddr];
        // safe and compiler allow since it is only 10 bits long max?
        int indx = static_cast<int>(address.to_ulong());
110:        // use the MSB or Pos 1 in 2 bit array to set boolean Take/Don't
        bool take = locprediction[indx].test(1);
        u.direction_prediction (take);
        u.target_prediction (0);
        return &u;
115:    }

    void update (branch_update *u, bool taken, unsigned int target) {

        if (bcopy.br_flags & BR_CONDITIONAL) {
120:            int lhtaddress = bcopy.address % LOCHISTTABLERNG;
            bitset<LHBITLEN> addr = lochisttab[lhtaddress];
            int indx = static_cast<int>(addr.to_ulong());
            for (int i=1; i < LHBITLEN; i++) {
                bool prval = lochisttab[lhtaddress].test(i-1);
125:                lochisttab[lhtaddress].set(i,prval);
            }
            bool prev = locprediction[indx].test(0);
            locprediction[indx].set(1,prev);

130:            if (taken) {
                lochisttab[lhtaddress].set(0);
                locprediction[indx].set(0);
            }
            else {
135:                lochisttab[lhtaddress].reset(0);
                locprediction[indx].reset(0);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Edit: I originally had no parantheses around the bitset arguments for the map declarations. The compiler gave the first error of "expected unqualified-id before 'for'". The template argument errors came from the parantheses (but I thought it was the result because of finally understanding the bitset data type potentially).

Comment: You can't put types in parentheses.

Comment: You seem to have `for` statements outside of any function.

Comment: I added the parantheses actually in response to getting the error the first time of "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’". The parantheses created the newer errors of the invalid arguments.

Comment: @n.m. Is a for loop initialization not allowed in the header class declaration?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the spurious parenthesis around `(bitset<LHBITLEN>)` on line 82 are the problem -- they probably cause the compiler to try to parse it as a template value parameter rather than a type parameter, and then get confused as it tries to recover.

As is often the case with a cascade of errors like this, only the first one is relevant and tells you what the problem is.  The later ones are caused by the compiler throwing away too many tokens as it tries to recover a meaningful context to continue, getting confused as to what it is looking at.  It probably threw away the `>` and `;` and thinks its still trying to parse a template parameter list when it sees the `for`

Comment: Now that you mention it: Is there a way to tell g++ to stop after the first error? Sometimes, especially when dealing with metatype, sfinae, enable_if etc. compiler messages become around 50 lines and the end is hard to see...

Comment: Thanks, and I edited to reflect that I added the parantheses after first getting the error around identification of 'for'. The other errors "error: ‘g’ does not name a type" were also still present originally. But the "int[int]" errors did not come up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax you need:

```
`map<int, bitset<10> > intBitsetMap;  //Note the space between the two: > >`
```

Comment: I did have a space originally between the > > and used the #define for a numerical value--is there significance in replacing the #define variable for the actual number?